# Use inputs.file for JavaExec task

Tags: gradle

Is [this](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1483) issue still actual? I am trying to use `input.files` for `JavaExec` task type with recent gradle 2.5 and have no effect. Task executed every time regardless of input files set.

So, here is my example:

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task sayHello(type: JavaExec) {
    inputs.files sourceSets.main.java
    main = "com.question.HelloGradle"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

`src/main/java/com/question/HelloGradle.java`

```
package com.question;

public class HelloGradle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, Gradle!");
    }
}
```

1. gradlew build
2. gradlew sayHello
3. gradlew sayHello

it will run second time, not up-to-date

but with workaround it executes only once

```
task sayHello(type: JavaExec) {
    inputs.files sourceSets.main.java
    outputs.upToDateWhen( { return true } );
    main = "com.question.HelloGradle"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample runnable script.

Comment: seems that I found solution with adding `outputs.upToDateWhen( { return true } );` to task

Comment: It's not a solution but rather a w workaround.

Comment: It's all described in the docs, have a look at: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks. You haven't defined any outputs. Both inputs and outputs are needed for up-to-date calculation.

Comment: If I add it as an answer, will you accept it?

Comment: sure, i will, please add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all described in the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks). You haven't defined any outputs. Both inputs and outputs are needed for *up-to-date* calculation.

Comment: Would you mind providing a minimal working example? I can't get it to work even with specifying the output

Comment: @piegames what's your concrete problem? If you have one, post a question.